# ViewModel Custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to create a custom JsonConverter that changes C# property names to camel case and javascript/json property names to pascal case. I feel like I'm on the right track but I'm having trouble understanding what I need to do (and I'm in a time crunch).

I realize I can add the `JsonProperty` attribute to my C# properties but I would prefer to apply an attribute to the class rather than each property.

```
public class ViewModelJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var model = JObject.Load(reader);
        var properties = model.Properties();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            RenameToPascalCase(prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
        return model;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var model = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(value);
        var properties = model.Properties();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            RenameToCamelCase(prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
    }


    private void RenameToCamelCase(string name, JToken value)
    {
        var parent = value.Parent;
        if (parent == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The parent is missing.");

        var newProperty = new JProperty(ToCamelCase(name), value);
        parent.Replace(newProperty);
    }

    private void RenameToPascalCase(string name, JToken value)
    {
        var parent = value.Parent;
        if (parent == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The parent is missing.");

        var newProperty = new JProperty(ToPascalCase(name), value);
        parent.Replace(newProperty);
    }

    //Example: propertyName
    private string ToCamelCase(string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || Char.IsLower(value, 0))
            return value;

        return Char.ToLowerInvariant(value[0]) + value.Substring(1);
    }

    //Example: PropertyName
    private string ToPascalCase(string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || Char.IsUpper(value, 0))
            return value;

        return Char.ToUpperInvariant(value[0]) + value.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

**Sample Use**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ViewModelJsonConverter))]
public class TestClass {
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Json.Net 9.0.1 or later, you can do what you want by using the `NamingStrategyType` parameter of the `[JsonObject]` attribute.  So, in other words, just mark the classes you want to be camel cased like this:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class TestClass
{
    ...
}
```

You don't need a `ContractResolver` or a custom `JsonConverter`.

Here is a round-trip demo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass
        {
            PropertyName = "foo",
            AnotherPropertyName = "bar"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("--- Serialize ---");
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tc, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("--- Deserialize ---");
        TestClass test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("PropertyName: " + test.PropertyName);
        Console.WriteLine("AnotherPropertyName: " + test.AnotherPropertyName);
    }
}

[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class TestClass
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string AnotherPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
--- Serialize ---
{
  "propertyName": "foo",
  "anotherPropertyName": "bar"
}

--- Deserialize ---
PropertyName: foo
AnotherPropertyName: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried any of these contract resolvers for newtonsoft json.
For eg:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

If you wanted to implement your own then please disregard.

Comment: I didn't know about this but I need to apply it to a specific class. This seems more like a global change. Is that right?

Comment: No, it happens before you call serialize or deserialize methods.